# Connect application server (GLPI) on-prem to Azure AD - Domain Service

Tags: centos7, entra-id, entra-domain-services

Can I really have an application server (with GLPI) on-prem and use Azure AD for the LDAP connection? For the explanation, I have installed GLPI on-prem (on CentOS - Linux) to create tickets and request for the user. I would like now open GLPI for the external client. 
I have different scenario, but I would like to try this one: Use GLPI on-prem but create a LDAP connector to Azure AD Domain Service (if I can?). I would like to use a dedicate tenant for the client, and manage the user account on this tenant, out of my environment but keep the application server on-prem..

Do you know if it's possible? How can I connect Azure AD Domain Service to my on-prem server? Or do I have to use a Point-to-point VPN?
I'm not sure if I can do that! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure AADDS for secure LDAP and provide a public IP to it.  You can then access it over the internet with no VPN required. I'm not familiar enough with GLPI however, to say if that would or would not work with it.

If you do a search for "AzureAD Secure LDAP" - you should find the Microsoft support articles.